# Pm2 running multiple instances by default in fork mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I have a very simple app.js file

```js
console.log("testing");
```

Running this with pm2 with the following command :

```
pm2 start app.js
```

This prints the lines below when doing pm2 logs 0;

```
0|app      | testing
0|app      | testing
0|app      | testing
0|app      | testing
0|app      | testing .. some more times as well.
```

I dont understand this behavior. Why is pm2 running this file multiple times. I have not specified any number of instances. Is default behavior is to spawn multiple instances by default in fork mode.

It does work fine when I specify instances to 1 and starts using the cluster mode. Official documentation doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

try this : 
pm2 list 
then show what is ur process running 
after that u can use this : 
pm2 reload [AppName]
if this not working 
check ur code u may have any error

Comment: There's only a single process in process list. The one I just started by pm2 start app.js

Comment: pm2 reload will simply start the process again.. How does that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

These logs might be due to multiple time execution of your application. Might be your application is getting restart multiple times hence multiple logging of the same console log. Check the number of restarts in pm2 list output.